# remove empty dimension of numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape (X,Y,Z). I want to check each of the Z dimension and delete the non-zero dimension really fast.

**Detailed explanation:**

I would like to check array[:,:,0] if any entry is non-zero.

If yes, ignore and check array[:,:,1].

Else if No, delete dimension array[:,:,0]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also not 100% sure what your after but I think you want

```
np.squeeze(array, axis=2)
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html

Comment: It is not needed to give an axis for empty dimensions. It finds it automatically.
There are also two ways for using it:
`np.squeeze(your_array)`
or
`your_array.squeeze()`

Comment: True, though I think the question was only wanting to check a specific dimension/axis. 
I do prefer the `array.squeeze(axis=2)` syntax though.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not certain what you want but this hopefully points in the right direction.

**Edit 1st Jan:**
Inspired by @J.Warren's use of np.squeeze I think np.compress may be more appropriate.

This does the compression in one line

```
np.compress((a!=0).sum(axis=(0,1)), a, axis=2) #
```

To explain the first parameter in np.compress

```
(a!=0).sum(axis=(0, 1)) # sum across both the 0th and 1st axes. 
Out[37]: array([1, 1, 0, 0, 2])  # Keep the slices where the array !=0
```

**My first answer which may no longer be relevant**

```
import numpy as np

a=np.random.randint(2, size=(3,4,5))*np.random.randint(2, size=(3,4,5))*np.random.randint(2, size=(3,4,5))
# Make a an array of mainly zeroes.
a
Out[31]:
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])

res=np.zeros(a.shape[2], dtype=np.bool)
for ix in range(a.shape[2]):
    res[ix] = (a[...,ix]!=0).any()

res
Out[34]: array([ True,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
# res is a boolean array of which slices of 'a' contain nonzero data

a[...,res]
# use this array to index a
# The output contains the nonzero slices
Out[35]:
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]]])
```